# Detaching and AppendingTo on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, window-resize

So I am trying to detach and appendTo a div based on window size. The following is what I currently have.

I am creating a function with a variable SOCIALBAR assigning it equal to #SOCIALMEDIA and detaching it.  Then based on window size for (document).ready and (window).resize, I call the SOCIALBARPlACEMENT function and #SOCIALMEDIA is either appendeto the #TOP or #LEFT divs.

This works fine and dandy on (document).ready but does not work for (window).resize.

In fact, if I remove document.ready, and leave window.resize, the function still runs on page load, but doesn't work on page resize.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thank!

```
function socialbarplacement() {
    var socialbar;
    socialbar = $("#socialmedia").detach();
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 1384) {
        socialbar.appendTo("#top");
    } else {
        socialbar.appendTo("#left");
    }
};
$(document).ready(socialbarplacement());
$(window).resize(socialbarplacement());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the functions immediately rather than passing them as event handlers, try:

```
$(document).ready(socialbarplacement);
$(window).resize(socialbarplacement);
/*
someFunction() <-- invokes the function and resolves to the returned value
someFunction <-- resolves to the function reference
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something along these line (untested code):

```
$(window).resize( function(){
    var wnd = $(window), soc = $('#socialmedia');
    return function(){
        // might add a check to make sure you are not appending to the current parent.
        soc.appendTo( $(window).width() > 1384 ? '#left' : '#top');
    }
});
```

Resize will get fired when the page loads so you don't need to have both on ready and resize.
  Also looking at it, you are executing the method when you really should be passing it in by name.

Answer (score 0):

I,ve try like this... Enjoy!

```js
$(function () {

   if (matchMedia) {
   var mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1384px)');
   var socialmedia = $("#socialmedia");
   mq.addListener(WidthChange);
   WidthChange(mq);
 }

 function WidthChange(mq) {
   if (mq.matches && socialmedia) {
  socialmedia.appendTo("#top");
  socialmedia = null; 
   } else {
  socialmedia = $("#socialmedia").detach(); 
        socialmedia.appendTo("#left");
   }
 };

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="top">
    <div id="socialmedia">SOCIALMEDIA</div> <br>
    **TOP**
  </div>
  
  <div id="left">
    <br>
    **LEFT** 
  </div>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```